# Differential of constraint equations

Tags: constraint

I have the following constraints equations :

```
SysCon = {-(1/2) l Cos[γ[t]] + Subscript[x, G][t] == 
   0, -(1/2) l Sin[γ[t]] + Subscript[y, G][t] == 0}
```

I would like to manipulate these expressions so as to obtain the equations in the following form :

$$ \phi _{q_d} \dot{q}_d+\phi _{q_i}\dot{q}_i$$

with $q_i = \gamma$ and $q_d = \{x_G, y_G\}$ and determine the matrix before $q_i$ and $q_d$.

May you help me to conduct this manipulation ?

I have tried without success the `Dt` function.

Comment: Perfect! You help me a lot. It answers to my question. However, how is it possible to generalize so that I can use directly my list qi and qd :
mat[[All, {1}]]
mat[[All, 2 ;; 3]]
I found in the help the function Position[ ] but It doesn't work. For example, I would like to obtain from a vector qd such as {xG,yG} a list of elements {1,2}

Comment: Pls remember to add the comments relevant to an answer with it (e.g. mat refers to something in the answer and not in the question.) I am not quite sure what you are asking, because it appears trivial what you are trying to do. I will update the answer. Hope that's what you want.

Answer (score 2):

This is the complete matrix

```
mat = D[First /@ SysCon, {{γ[t], Subscript[x, G][t], Subscript[y, G][t]}}]
```

> [image]

and these are the individual matrices

```
mat[[All, {1}]]
```

> [image]

```
mat[[All, 2 ;; 3]]
```

> [image]

**Update**

Generalizing a bit:

```
eqns = SysCon /. Equal[lhs_, rhs_] :> lhs - rhs;
Subscript[q, i] = {γ};
Subscript[q, d] = {Subscript[x, G], Subscript[y, G]};
toT[var : _[t]] := var
toT[var_] := var[t]
```

The matrices:

```
{Subscript[ϕ, Subscript[q, i]], Subscript[ϕ, Subscript[q,  d]] } = 
D[eqns, {toT /@ #}] & /@ {Subscript[q, i], Subscript[q, d]};
MatrixForm /@ %
```

[image]